# undefined is not an object( evaluating 'region.address_lat')

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am getting this error while running my React-Native project. Can anyone help me with this issue?

I'm using:

- Expo Version: 2.4.0
- React Native Version: 0.55.4
- React Native CLI: 2.0.1

[image: error]

Comment: Post error in the text format! and also relevant code which throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you trying get field of object before you get object. Try [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), it should help